# Displaying a scrolling stock exchange ticker in a window

Tags: python, object-oriented, multithreading, classes, tkinter

I've written my first OOP program (194 lines including docstring and comments) in Python that uses Tkinter as GUI and Threads.  The program shows a window and displays a scrolling stock exchange ticker in a line.

I've created the following classes:

- A class that draws the GUI layout with Tkinter library.
- A class for the tickers, with the data of each securities.
- A class for manage the stock exchange market and dispatch the data to the GUI.
- The Thread subclass for updating the stock exchange values every certain time interval.

The code seems very ugly to me.  I would like some feedback about the code structure, especially about the use of OOP.

```
#!usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import time
import threading
from random import randint as randint, uniform as randlimit


class AplicationTkinter(Frame):
    """
    Class of tkinter.Frame subclass, Initializes the GUI
    methods:
        initGUI, draws the layout
        scroll_ticker, inserts character by character in the Text widget
    """
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.initGUI()
        self.scroll_ticker()

    def initGUI(self):
        # changes the window icon
        self.parent.iconbitmap("tabla.ico")
        self.parent.title("Stock Exchange Ticker")
        # fix a status bar at the bottom of the window, for future improvements
        self.status_bar = Label(self.parent, text="", bd=1, relief=SUNKEN, anchor=W)
        self.status_bar.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        # content Frame for entry, for future improvements
        self.frm_1 = Frame(self.parent)
        self.frm_1.pack()
        self.var_entry = StringVar()
        self.ent_1 = Entry(self.frm_1, textvariable=self.var_entry)
        self.ent_1.pack()
        self.var_entry.set("a default value")
        str_ent_1 = self.ent_1.get()
        # content LabelFrame to show the ticker scrolling line of text
        self.lblfr_1 = LabelFrame(self.parent, text="Ventana de Resultados")
        self.lblfr_1.pack()
        # creates an instance of the StockMarket class for contents the the data
        self.market_one = StockMarket(stock_market)
        # the scrolling line of Text for show the data
        self.txt_ticker_widget = Text(self.lblfr_1, background='black', height=1, width=56, wrap="none")
        self.txt_ticker_widget.pack(side=TOP, fill=X)
        self.txt_ticker_widget.tag_configure("up", foreground="green")
        self.txt_ticker_widget.tag_configure("down", foreground="red")
        self.txt_ticker_widget.tag_configure("even", foreground="white")
        self.tag = {CHAR_DOWN: "down", CHAR_EVEN: "even", CHAR_UP: "up"}

    def scroll_ticker(self):
        self.txt_ticker_widget.configure(state=NORMAL)
        self.txt_ticker_widget.insert(END, self.market_one.get_next_character(),
                                      self.tag[self.market_one.get_tag()])  # TODO simplify
        self.txt_ticker_widget.see(END)
        self.txt_ticker_widget.configure(state=DISABLED)
        self.txt_ticker_widget.after(SPEED, self.scroll_ticker)  # recursive each interval of millisecs


# Here starts the program working process, until here was the GUI
# CONSTANTS
CHAR_UP = "\u25B2"
CHAR_DOWN = "\u25BC"
CHAR_EVEN = "="
SPEED = 250
UPDATE_TIME = 60

# INITIAL DATA, this must be changed to implement the load of a external source
stock_market = [["GOOG", "587.25", CHAR_UP, "(+12.14)"],
                ["AAPL", "237.14", CHAR_UP, "(+7.25)"],
                ["GTAT", "87.47", CHAR_DOWN, "(-1.18)"],
                ["KNDI", "167.32", CHAR_UP, "(+6.85)"],
                ["ORCL", "482.91", CHAR_DOWN, "(-24.65)"],
                ["FBOK", "327.67", CHAR_DOWN, "(-11.78)"],
                ["TWTR", "842.41", CHAR_UP, "(+15.45)"]]


class StockTicker():
    """
    Class StockTicker, handle each stock symbol and their data
    attributes:
        symbol, string, the abbreviature of the securitie
        price, string, the current price of the securitie
        direction, string(1), is a character that indicates its las fix price went up, down or even
        change, string, is the value of the last change surrounded by '()', the first character is '+' or '-'
    methods:
        update_ticker, update the securitie price, direction and change with random values
        ticker_to_text, returns a formatted string with all the data of the securitie
    """
    def __init__(self, list_data):
        self.symbol, self.price, self.direction, self.change = list_data

    def update_ticker(self):
        flt_price = float(self.price)
        if randint(0, 9) == 0:
            self.direction = CHAR_EVEN
        else:
            increase_percent = randlimit(-5, 5)
            # TODO implementar normalvariate(0, 0.02) o gauss(0, 0.02)
            flt_change = flt_price * increase_percent / 100
            flt_new_price = flt_price + flt_change
            self.price = "{:.2f}".format(flt_new_price)
            if flt_change < 0:
                self.direction = CHAR_DOWN
            elif flt_change == 0:
                self.direction = CHAR_EVEN
            else:
                self.direction = CHAR_UP
            self.change = "({:+.2f})".format(flt_change)

    def ticker_to_text(self):
        return " |  {} {} {} {} ".format(self.symbol, self.price, self.direction, self.change)


class StockMarket():
    """
    Class StockMarket, creates and handle a list of StockTicker objects, and provide to the GUI of stuff for
        the scroll ticker
    attributes:
        smarket, list of StockTicker objects
        thread_actualizar, Thread object to update the stock market each time interval
    methods:
        load_market, load the list with StockTicker object taking the data from the initial source data.
        update_market, update the objects of the list
        get_one_ticker, getter function to return one securitie data in text format and rotates to the next one
        get_next_character, returns a character of one securitie (if the securitie data is exhausted
            retrieve another securitie) data to the GUI.
    """
    def __init__(self, l_inicial):
        self.smarket = []
        self.load_market(l_inicial)
        self.current_ticker = self.get_one_ticker()
        self.thread_updating = UpdateThread(self)
        self.thread_updating.start()

    def load_market(self, l_inicial):
        for data_ticker in l_inicial:
            simple_ticker = StockTicker(data_ticker)
            self.smarket.append(simple_ticker)

    def update_market(self):
        for j in range(len(self.smarket)):
            self.smarket[j].update_ticker()

    def get_one_ticker(self):
        self.one_ticker = self.smarket.pop(0)
        self.smarket.append(self.one_ticker)
        self.index = 0
        return self.one_ticker.ticker_to_text()

    def get_next_character(self):
        if self.index == len(self.current_ticker):
            self.current_ticker = self.get_one_ticker()
            self.index = 0
        self.character_symbol = self.current_ticker[self.index:self.index+1]
        self.index += 1
        return self.character_symbol

    def get_tag(self):
        return self.one_ticker.direction


class UpdateThread(threading.Thread):
    """
    Class UpdateThread(), subclass of Thread, handle the time to the next update of the stock market values
    args:
        market_1, a StockMarket class object to update
    attributes:
        my_check, string for debugging purpouses, it'll be implemented the source data management
        the_market, StockMarket object that will be updated
    methods:
        run, overrides the Thread run method, and calls the update_market method of StockMarket class each interval
    """
    def __init__(self, market_1):
        self.my_check = " CHECK "   # TODO replace with initial source data.
        self.the_market = market_1
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        time.sleep(UPDATE_TIME)
        self.the_market.update_market()
        print(" UPDATED!!!")    # for debugging
        self.run()


# STARTS THE PROGRAM
def main():
    the_window = Tk()
    aplicacion = AplicationTkinter(the_window)
    # init the GUI process
    the_window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know there are some lines that I could have written in a unique line, but for now I'd like to be explicit.

Or expressions that can be simplified like:

```
if not randint(0, 9):
```

instead of:

```
if randint(0, 9) == 0:
```

Comment: I have just taken a quick look at the code, but I wanted to share my first impression. I see that the docstrings are in English, but that many variables names are written in Spanish (ventana, aplicacion, precio, cambio, ...). I'm a Spaniard myself and I understand the variable names, but if you wish to get them reviewed by an international community, you should use English everywhere.

Comment: Thank for the annotation @jcollado, I'll bear in mind for future. I'm a Spaniard too!

Comment: I've already translated all the var names to english.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some comments:

- There's a slash missing in the path to the python3 binary
- Beware of lines longer than 80 characters ([pep8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/))
- Constants should be at the top of the file
- Constanst used only in one class, should be class attributes (for example, `SPEED`)
- Use docstrings for every method (do not describe each method in the class docstring) ([pep257](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/))
- Using [sphinx formatting](http://sphinx-doc.org/domains.html#info-field-lists) for the docstring is a good idea
- Try to avoid `from tkinter import *`. An alternative to still keep short names would be `import tkinter as tk` and the code would be a little bit more readable
- Review the variable names. If there is just one frame, use `self.frame` instead of `self.frm_1`. If there is just label frame use `self.label_frame` instead of `self.lblfr_1`. I'm not aware of any convention for tk, but I find the current variable names hard to read
- Also, do not use `self.` when the variable is just used in that method and never again. This makes the reader think that variable is going to be used later when is not.
- Use well known methods when possible. `ticker_to_text` sounds pretty much like it should be `__str__`.
- There are some methods that seem to be used only internally like, for example, `get_one_ticker`. Prefix them with an underscore to make clear they are private.
- Try to set all attributes needed in the `__init__` method. If there's no value available at initialization time, then set them to `None`. This provides the reader with the information of all the attributes used to keep the object internal state.
- Note that `self.current_ticker[self.index:self.index+1]` is `self.current_ticker[self.index]`
- Avoid verbosity in method names. For instance, `Market.load_market` should be `Market.load`
- Implement iteration properly, that is, instead of `for j in range(len(self.smarket))` use `for ticker in self.smarket` (and rename `smarket` to `tickers`)
- Make sure the update thread is stopped when the application is closed (that doesn't happen currently)

Rearding the object oriented design, I think it's good already. I see there's an application class that takes care of the GUI, a stock market class that handles all the tickers, a ticker class that keeps the data for each ticker and a thread that asks the market to update itself periodically.

All in all, if you fix the readability issues, I think the code can be pretty good. Actually, I looked at the application running and the output is already quite nice.

Comment: Thanks a lot @jcollado.  I've done all your suggestions, except: -_Using sphinx formatting_ (more later, procrastination...), -_ticker_to_text sounds pretty much like it should be __str__._ (I don't undertand this), -_Avoid verbosity in method names_ (I had to mantain `update_market` and `updater_ticker` to avoid conflicts. -_Make sure the update thread is stopped..._ (I don't know how, yet)  I also read your blog, it's an interesting issue.

Comment: [`__str__`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) is the method called by the `str` and `print` when they need to know what is the default text representation of an object. Hence, having a method with a different name, but the same functionality is not considered a good practice. Regarding the update methods, it's not a problem to have an `update` method in two different classes. In fact, I think it's better because the reader quickly gets that their purpose is the same.

Comment: Regarding the thread, instead of `time.sleep`, I'd use something like `threading.Event` to signal from the GUI code that the application is finished. I don't know how tk works specifically, but there should be some event/signal that can be captured to know that the main loop is about to exit.

Answer (score 4):

One suggestion is to change the `stock_market` structure from a list to a dictionary.

```
stock_market = {'GOOG': {'Value': 587.25, 'Change': 12.14},
                'APPL': {'Value': 237.14, 'Change': 7.25}
               }
```

You also don't need to hard code "CHAR_UP", "CHAR_DOWN" toggles when those can be evaluated with the sign of `change` in the dict.

```
if stock_market['GOOG']['Change'] > 0.:
    direction = 'CHAR_UP'
else:
    direction = 'CHAR_DOWN'
```

Comment: The data structure of the stock_market is a meanwhile solution, the ultimate will a web extracting data process.  The seccond issue is a useful simplification, but I'm looking for:  _...obout the code structure, especially about the use of OOP._